# Why does Android system always call Garbage Collector every time i make a request to web server?

Tags: android, performance, garbage-collection

Why does Android system always call garbage collection every time I make a request to web server to get images? Although I did every actions are asynchronous. Calling GC too many times make my app delays when scrolling or fling.

Update: I guess Android system always call GC when you do something request to web server. Here is the log when using the Android default browser. Each time you click on a link GC will be called automatically.

```
03-08 16:36:19.530: D/dalvikvm(341): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2124K, 31% free 10780K/15623K, paused 49ms
03-08 16:36:19.590: D/dalvikvm(341): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 20% free 12635K/15623K, paused 49ms
03-08 16:36:19.700: D/dalvikvm(341): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 20% free 12635K/15623K, paused 3ms+4ms
03-08 16:36:22.610: D/dalvikvm(20845): GC_CONCURRENT freed 735K, 10% free 9018K/9991K, paused 2ms+6ms
03-08 16:36:25.620: D/dalvikvm(20845): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1046K, 12% free 8954K/10119K, paused 4ms+3ms
03-08 16:36:27.880: D/dalvikvm(2781): GC_EXPLICIT freed 263K, 7% free 6373K/6791K, paused 2ms+2ms
03-08 16:36:28.950: D/dalvikvm(20845): GC_CONCURRENT freed 884K, 12% free 8946K/10119K, paused 3ms+3ms
03-08 16:36:29.760: D/dalvikvm(20845): GC_CONCURRENT freed 861K, 12% free 8949K/10119K, paused 3ms+3ms
03-08 16:36:31.390: D/dalvikvm(285): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1275K, 38% free 20843K/33223K, paused 17ms+8ms
03-08 16:36:31.510: D/dalvikvm(20845): GC_CONCURRENT freed 810K, 12% free 8946K/10119K, paused 3ms+5ms
03-08 16:36:38.100: D/dalvikvm(20845): GC_CONCURRENT freed 730K, 11% free 9027K/10119K, paused 3ms+6ms
03-08 16:36:40.920: D/dalvikvm(20845): GC_CONCURRENT freed 864K, 12% free 8989K/10119K, paused 2ms+5ms
03-08 16:36:45.780: D/dalvikvm(20845): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 620K, 12% free 8909K/10119K, paused 41ms
03-08 16:36:48.250: D/dalvikvm(20845): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 499K, 12% free 9002K/10119K, paused 45ms
03-08 16:36:48.570: D/dalvikvm(20845): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 225K, 13% free 8899K/10119K, paused 28ms
03-08 16:36:50.670: D/dalvikvm(20845): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 388K, 12% free 8915K/10119K, paused 34ms
03-08 16:36:52.550: D/dalvikvm(20845): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 511K, 11% free 9008K/10119K, paused 44ms
03-08 16:36:53.780: D/dalvikvm(20845): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 273K, 12% free 8909K/10119K, paused 42ms
03-08 16:37:05.070: D/dalvikvm(569): GC_EXPLICIT freed 376K, 12% free 6207K/6983K, paused 2ms+2ms
03-08 16:37:25.550: D/dalvikvm(2549): GC_CONCURRENT freed 337K, 9% free 7198K/7879K, paused 2ms+3ms
03-08 16:37:31.330: D/dalvikvm(2549): GC_EXPLICIT freed 54K, 10% free 7143K/7879K, paused 7ms+2ms
03-08 16:38:45.630: D/dalvikvm(2549): GC_EXPLICIT freed 268K, 10% free 7161K/7879K, paused 7ms+2ms
```

Comment: can you paste the code to connect to web and what is do.

Comment: How do you know it's calling garbage collection, out of curiosity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android GC is automatic, opaque, non-deterministic. Which means *you have nothing can do on it*.

Traditionally, this type of GC works like this.

- Wait until enough garbages are generated.
- If GC engine thinks it's time, it stops your app.
- Clear the garbages
- Resume your app.

Of course, this sucks for end-use UI and graphics.
So Google added *incremental collection*. Essentially, this is just doing above procedure more frequently with less garbages. So pause time itself would be short but collection itself happens a lot more frequently.

As a conclusion, garbage collection happens randomly, but very frequently. So it would look happening always for any of operations.

Practically, there's no *guaranteed* way to avoid GC lag on typical GC systems.